# how can i set in FFMPEG the video codec for a high quality avi?

Tags: linux

hi im a begginer in using FFMPEG as a video audio converter, I wonder if someone can help me how to set parameters through FFMPEG in DOS ccommand that will result to a little compressed but still a high quaity video, or what I meant was how to set thequality for at least 70-90% of the original video quaity..

thanks pls.. I need response..

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get more quality out of flash is to raise your encoding rate (vbitrate=800 to vbitrate=1200, for example). This will, however, result in much larger files and will require your visitors to have to have internet connections of at least 1.5Mb to view your videos without stuttering all of the time.

Comment: ffmpeg -i input -vb 800k output      ,does it goes like this?

Comment: it is correct, i think its better to use flv thatn avi format  see http://forums.buyscripts.in/installation-support/266-video-quality.html see this site for further information

Comment: thanks for that.. just one more question.. i also try using the ffmpeg_php.. and I encounter warning such the exeeding limit of maximum bytes.. does it natural or I just improperly code my scripts..